# Adding a horizontal line to graphs

Tags: matlab, plot, line

So I've got this plot that has 2 curves, and I'm trying to add the last curve(A3 = .1) on a `loglog` plot. For some reason it won't plot anything. Code is below.

```
f = logspace(-2,1);
A = 10./f.^2;
A3 = .1;
A2 = A + A3;
loglog(f,A,'--')
loglog(f,A2,':')
loglog(f,A3)
hold on
grid on
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior, as in your example every subsequent `loglog` plot "overwrites" the preceding. Also the size of `A3` does not match the size of `f` and that's why you cannot see this line on a plot. So, to solve those issues:

(1) You should place the `hold on` function right after the first plot that belongs to a "stack" (as described in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html).

```
f = logspace(-2,1);
A = 10./f.^2;
A3 = .1;
A2 = A + A3;
loglog(f,A,'--')
hold on
loglog(f,A2,':')
loglog(f,A3)
grid on
```

(2) You should expand `A3` to the correct size: `loglog(f,A3 * ones(size(A)))`

Answer (score 0):

For this there is a very nice utility on the Matlab File Exchange: [hline/vline](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1039-hline-and-vline). Additionally it internally calls `hold on` to avoid erasing existing lines on the plot.